# Cannot get the correct data out of a file using stringWithContentsOfFile

Tags: objective-c, macos, encoding

I haven been working on this problem for a couple of hours but I still could not get it worked. I have tried all the solutions I found on stackoverflow but nothing worked. The following is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
NSFileManager *fileManager;
NSString *currentPath;
NSString *content;
content = [[NSString alloc] init];

NSString *filename;
filename = @"/Tasty Noodle House.xlsx";

fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
currentPath = [fileManager currentDirectoryPath];

NSError*  error;
content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[currentPath stringByAppendingString:filename] encoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding error:&error];

NSLog(@"current path: %@",currentPath);
NSLog(@"filecontent: %@",content);
NSLog( @"error: %@", error );
```

}

I have checked that the path is correct and the file did exist in that path(currentPath). However, the problem is that the line NSLog(@"filecontent: %@",content); is not printed out at all. The printout looks like the following:

```
2016-01-23 11:30:11.367 ScaryBugsMac[1377:222946] current path: /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ScaryBugsMac-buobqwjccigdqthjejrzmgasnzyf/Build/Products/Debug
2016-01-23 11:30:11.367 ScaryBugsMac[1377:222946] error: (null)
```

Based on my experience, it should print out at least "filecontent: (null)".But it is really weird nothing get printed out.

I have also tried using the enconding: **NSUTF8StringEncoding**, it gave me the error:

```
2016-01-23 11:32:44.708 ScaryBugsMac[1404:230157] current path: /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ScaryBugsMac-buobqwjccigdqthjejrzmgasnzyf/Build/Products/Debug
2016-01-23 11:32:44.708 ScaryBugsMac[1404:230157] filecontent: (null)
2016-01-23 11:32:44.709 ScaryBugsMac[1404:230157] error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=261 "The file “Tasty Noodle House.xlsx” couldn’t be opened using text encoding Unicode (UTF-8)." UserInfo=0x60000007a740 {NSFilePath=/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ScaryBugsMac-buobqwjccigdqthjejrzmgasnzyf/Build/Products/Debug/Tasty Noodle House.xlsx, NSStringEncoding=4}
```

Two other things:

1. I have tried all the encodings and the problem falls into one of the two cases above.
2. I could open the xlsx file using Excel on my Mac without any problem. So I don't think there is anything wrong with the file.

I would really appreciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More likely than not, the file contents are either compressed (IIRC, the XLSX definition allows the contents to be straight-compressed).

Or there are characters in the file that are, effectively, causing it to be considered corrupt.

Loading it into an NSString probably isn't that useful.   If it is compressed, you'll need to decompress it first.    If it truly is an XLSX file, then you'll want to use, at least, an XML reader to read the contents (and, better yet, some likely already available open source library that can read said file's contents).

Comment: Thank you! I'll go look for the open source tool for reading and parsing excel file in objective-c

Answer (score 0):

Excel .xlsx files contain binary data. A .xlsx file is similar to a package bundle.

It does not contain plain text, therefore it cannot be encoded to `NSString`